# What is it called when we "zoom in" a data distribution?

Tags: distributions, terminology, subset

Suppose we have a 2D distribution of shops in an area.  For example, here is a heatmap density plot of (latitude, longitude) location of shops in a province: 
[image]

Now suppose that we "zoom into" the distribution and consider only a tiny window $w:([x_1,x_2],[y_1,y_2])$ inside the whole range of x,y; so that we can have a better insight into how data points (shops) are arranged in the small local neighbourhoods.

The data distribution INSIDE each random window is obviously a subset of the entire data. For example, if we plot shops with latitude between $[42, 42.3]$ and longitude between $[-76, -75.5]$, we get this distribution: (visualized with scatterplot)

[image]

In the statistics community, **what is the actual name of these "zoomed in" parts of a data distribution?**

I want to report that the data distribution is skew in general, but quite uniform in "those small subsets". What are those distributions inside the windows called?

May I say, for example, "micro-distribution" or "partial distribution"?

Comment: Notice that you can always edit a question, not need to delete and ask new question. In fact, we generally discourage deleting and re-asking, in vast majority of cases it will yield a moderator reaction.

Comment: @Tim yep, thanks for the hint & sorry for the repost; but I realized that my initial post was so badly written that it drifted all comment to irrelevant subjects (such as the type of the charts, the scale of the features, etc).

Comment: Detail view of ...

Comment: If your goal is to talk about some property, you can just say that the property applies "locally" or "in this region"

Comment: @user20160, I am indexing a multidimensional data which splits the data into a grid. I am interested in the data distribution inside each grid cell. Is "local distribution" a common term in statistics?

Comment: @Ali no, "local distribution" isn't a standard term. The phrasing I suggested is a way to talk about local properties of the entire distribution. For example, one could say something like "the distribution is multimodal, but the density is approximately uniform within each cell of the grid". (But, notice that one can define a grid such that this is trivially true for *any* well-behaved distribution. So, for this statement to be informative, it depends on the nature of the grid)

Answer (score 1):

This would be the conditional distribution, conditional on $x\in[x_1,x_2]$ and $y\in[y_1,y_2]$.

Your phrasing of “zoom in” is descriptive and might be worth including, something like, “We also zoom in on the window to show the conditional distribution...”

Comment: Agree with second paragraph, but I'd be reluctant to use "conditional" for describing data manipulations. Conditional probability is a probabilistic term, here we are talking about filtering the data. I wouldn't mix those.